# Unknown function: NERDTreeAddKeyMap

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, nerdtree

I'm trying to add a keymap to my NERDTree configuration which executes the current FileNode and displays the output. I put this script file in my **~/.vim/plugin** directory.

The keymap actually works when I source the script file from within Vim, but displays the error **"Unknown function: NERDTreeAddKeyMap"** when starting Vim.

I used [Pathogen](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen) for my plugins, and in my **~/.vimrc** I have all the necessary :

```
" Enable filetype plugins
filetype plugin indent on

" Start Pathogen plugin to load bundle
call pathogen#infect()
call pathogen#helptags()
```

As well as NERDTree in my **~/.vim/bundle** directory.

Where should I move the script so that it is automatically loaded on Vim startup, without this ugly error ?

Comment: did you call `NERDTreeAddKeyMap` before the Nerdtree loaded?  try to put it after your pathogen calls.

Comment: That's what I guessed, but I have my pathogen calls in my vimrc and I want the script to be loaded after loading the plugins, is there any way I can acheive this ?

Comment: for example, add it at the end of your .vimrc?

Comment: I'd like to do this without touching my vimrc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The `filetype plugin indent on` line is supposed to come *after* the two Pathogen lines.
2. [The relevant documentation](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/blob/master/doc/NERD_tree.txt#L1042) says:

   > This code should sit in a file like `~/.vim/nerdtree_plugin/mymapping.vim`.

   So, since you use Pathogen, the right place is probably:

   ```
   ~/.vim/bundle/[nerdtree directory]/nerdtree_plugin/mymapping.vim
   ```